# Slow execution of Exe in Azure

Tags: azure, exe

I am facing a problem of slow execution of exe in Azure platform

Following are the Steps:

1. Read data from SQL Azure Server& CSV files & display in on HTML5 pages.
2. Write data on CSV files.
3. Executing a external Fortron exe, which reads data from csv files generated in step 23.
4. Fortron exe after calculations write data on .txt file.
5. Read text file data generated in step 5 & display it on HTML5 pages.

Issue:
In point # 3, when we are invoking fortron exe using process start method, then –
    On local machines in usually take 17~18 secs
    On cloud server this is taking 34~35 secs.

Rest all other activities are taking same time on local as well as cloud server.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding step 3: What size local machine are you using (e.g. number of cores), since you're running an exe that may be doing some number-crunching. Now compare that the the machine size allocated in Windows Azure? Are you using an Extra Small (shared core) or Small (single core)? Plus what size cpu does your local machine have? If you're not comparing like-kind configurations, you'll certainly have performance differences. Same goes for RAM (an Extra Small offers 768MB, with Small through XL offering 1.75GB per core) and bandwidth (XS has 5Mbps, Small through XL have 100Mbps per core).

Comment: David thanks for reply- I am using Pentium I5 machine with 4 GB ram. in Azure I have 8 GB VM (i.e. large instance).

Answer (score 0):

The Azure systems have slower IO process than a local server this will be the reason you see the performance impact you are also on a shared system so your IO also may vary depending on your neighbours also and server load. If you are task is IO intensive the best bet is to run a VM and you need to persist the data is to attach multiple disks to the VM and then use stripping on the disk.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/attach-a-disk/

Striped IO Disks performance stats.

http://blinditandnetworkadmin.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/vm-io-performance-on-windows-azure.html

You will need to have a warm set of disks to get true performance set.

Also I found the Temp storage on VM Normally the D drive to have very good IO so maybe worth *if* you are going to use a VM to try there first.

Comment: OP mentioned using `Start()` method. This implies web/worker role instance, which means it's not shared resources and not neighbor-affected. Not sure why you're suggesting using a VM over web/worker, since web/worker instances are virtual machines, just stateless and not backed by user-managed vhd. Local disk is ephemeral (attached).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Point well made ;) that he has be talking about web/worker role ;) I suggested VM on the grounds that you can increase the IO speed of disks and he was talking in regards to point 3 that he starts a Fortran process that is IO heavy and reads CSV files. I could be wrong but I thought IO at disk level was effected by neighbours in web/worker roles. I can never get out of MS a agreement on IO speed. Happy to be wrong ;) We run lucence search at compute in that environment and test it regularly and seems to go up and down in speed based on IO available in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for comment- but I doubt attaching the new disk will change anything. but I have doubt, it may be possible hard disks are shared in Azure, & sometimes writing data on shared resource will take more time in compare to local system.

Comment: Attaching a just one disk will not work I mean adding a Strip set of disks.